Are microwave oven transformers usually bigger if designed for 230V vs 120V?
Consider a 1kW microwave oven designed with versions for both Europe and USA.  The 50 Hz of Europe should theoretically force a slightly bigger, and more expensive, transformer, but what about the higher voltage?
My thinking is that primary coil inductance would need to be doubled if the voltage gets doubled (to limit current below saturation levels), so the primary coil might need like 140 turns instead of 100 turns, but there are many other counteracting effects too (e.g., since the primary current gets halved, resistive losses are smaller and the primary wire can therefore be thinner).
All things considered, are microwave oven transformers usually more expensive to build for Europe?  I would prefer to ask this question for South Korea or Peru (220V and 60 Hz) to eliminate the frequency effect, but I think that limits the answers too much...

Saturation is determined by turns per volt, so at constant frequency, doubling the input voltage would require doubling the turns.
An easy way to intuit what's happening would be to imagine the transformer primary is wound with two equal windings, each taking 120 V. If they are connected in parallel, you supply 120 V at a high current. If they are connected in series, then you supply 240 V with half the current. Same power, same magnetic fields, same losses, just different thickness of wire and number of turns to fill the available winding space. In fact, there's no need to imagine. Many transformers are built with a 2-winding primary specifically for 120/240 V operation.
Changing the frequency changes things, but a microwave oven transformer is an unusually compromised beast, so it's not quite as big a change as you would think.
If saturation was a hard limit, and the frequency dropped from 60 Hz to 50 Hz, then you would need to increase the number of turns by another 20% above the voltage difference. However, MOTs are built down to a price, operated well into saturation, and transformer dissipation is the limiting factor 1. With fewer cycles per second round the core hysteresis loop, this permits a higher energy loss per cycle, so the core can be worked further into saturation, reducing the number of extra turns needed. There's not much difference, apart from roughly 2x primary turns and 50% wire area, between a US and European MOT.
1 With the manufacturer paying for the cost of materials, but the customer paying for the electricity, there's absolutely no incentive to make an efficient transformer.

Thanks to the 3 people who answered similarly (but this answer came first).  So, primary has twice the turns but half of the wire area, so the effects cancel almost perfectly for no added cost.  But, I don't understand how "fewer cycles per second" is "reducing the number of extra turns needed".  Maybe you meant to instead write "more cycles per second"?  Or, can you clarify this more?

Ok.  If I understand you, the 20% increase in number of turns is partly offset by less dissipation (which would, for example, allow the designer to make the coil wire a little thinner), but overall theoretical cost will still increase when the operating frequency drops from 60 Hz to 50 Hz.  As for the voltage effect, it seems to be a perfect tie so far, so I'd like to wait a little before marking any answer (to see if anyone points out some secondary effects that make lower or higher voltages cheaper).

Generally speaking, for the same frequency and for other parameters constant, the size (and therefore the approximate cost) of the transformer will be fixed by the VA. Assuming we’re talking about old-fashioned mains transformers and not modern inverter microwave ovens.
For 230VAC the primary will have more turns of thinner wire than for 120VAC. About the same amount of copper. The cost difference of that is insignificant.
Now if you start talking about 2400VAC primary or 6VAC it will be different because of insulation requirements or because of the difficulty of dealing with high current magnet wire and filling the window with it.
The frequency effect is about 20%, so that could account for a price difference but probably no more than 10% in OEM volume- the material costs don't map directly to component cost. The transformers are pared to the bone cost-wise- compare the size of industrial control transformers of similar VA,
Generally, I think, electrical items made properly for Europe also cost more because of more stringent safety and other standards and a preference for higher quality product compared to US consumer preferences, at least for the mass market. There is also a high end market in the US, of course, and you might find some European brands represented there as well as domestic brands. And European retail prices typically include VAT at as much as 25% whereas US prices are almost always net of sales tax.

As a matter of manufacturing economics, the 120V versus 240V conundrum is
often treated by wiring two identical primaries, and connecting them
in parallel for 120V, or series for 240V.   It doesn't
even take any extra time (indeed, by starting two windings at once,
the bobbin only has to rotate half as much to finish the 240V winding job).
Unless the economics are odd, I'd expect that one-size-fits-all
conservative design would be used for transformers, and a wiring
change would be part of the AC cord/plug/fuse for the local electricity.

For the record, I've taken apart 2 USA microwave oven transformers in my life and neither had two primary coils in parallel, so I don't know if "often" is the right word, but what you say makes sense.
